# How does GSSManager.createCredential get the Kerberos key and TGT?

Tags: java, kerberos, spnego, subject, gss

I have the following scenario:
I have a server that runs inside an Oracle database (with Java SE 6) that connects to a web service, using the Apache HTTP client (in Java). The web service needs to be protected using Kerberos, i.e. with SPNEGO authentication.

My server has a Kerberos principal, with a random key exported to a keytab, and then imported into a database table.
So I have a KerberosPrincipal with a number of associated KerberosKey objects (one for each encryption method), all that information I have collected in a Subject.

I expect that the next step is to contact the KDC in order to get the TGT and store it in the Subject. How do I do that? All the documentation I have found on this assumes that this happens in a login module, but there is no login in my scenario. Or will one of the below call the KDC for me?

Now i need to call GSSManager.createCredential to create a GSSCredential which I can wrap into a KerberosCredentials and a BasicCredentialsProvider that I can add to the HttpClientContext, so the HttpClient can do the SPNEGO authentication.

But how do I get info in my Subject into the GSSCredential?

Answer (score 2):

After digging around the web for about a week, I finally found the answer [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/guides/security/jgss/single-signon.html).
Snippet from that doc:

1. The application invokes a JAAS login, which in turn invokes the configured Krb5LoginModule
2. Krb5LoginModule obtains a TGT (KerberosTicket) for the user either from the KDC or from an existing ticket cache, and stores this TGT in the private credentials set of a Subject
3. The application retrieves the populated Subject, then calls Subject.doAs/doAsPrivileged which places this Subject on the access control context of the thread executing ClientAction
4. ClientAction calls the GSSManager.createCredential method, passing it the Kerberos V5 OID in desiredMechs.
5. GSSManager.createCredential invokes the Kerberos V5 GSS-API provider, asking for a Kerberos credential for initiating security contexts.
6. The Kerberos provider obtains the Subject from the current access control context, and searches through its private credential set for a valid KerberosTicket that represents the TGT for the user.
7. The KerberosTicket is returned to the GSSManager which stores it in a GSSCredential container instance to be returned to the caller.